# How to update metadata outside the code in php?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it is possible to update keyword, description and other meta tags outside the code? Lets say there would be a cms and all pages are listed. User who does SEO, should be able to edit keywords there. Is such thing possible? I tired searching but could not find any results.

Here is meta.php where I have the tags

```
<?php

function meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc, $pgTitle)
{?>
     <title><?php echo $pgTitle ?></title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>">
     <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>"><?php
 }?>
```

Here is a sample page:

```
<head>
    require_once('PHP/meta.php');
    $pgTitle="My page | Login";
    $pgKeywords="keyword1, keyword2";
    $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc, $pgTitle);
</head>
```

Comment: Sure you can.  What's your problem?

Comment: @Progrock any tips? I tried searching for a tutorial or such but no avail. Kind of puzzled here.

Comment: Form with fields route/url and meta attributes.  Post and store somewhere.  Then when displaying page, retrieve from your store the associated meta data values and pass through your above function.

Comment: @Progrock so store data in database for example right?

Comment: Sure if that's what floats your boat.

Comment: @Progrock thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

find bellow code

```
function meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc, $pgTitle)
{?>
    $html="";

     $html .= '<title><?php echo $pgTitle ?></title>';
     $html .= '<meta charset="utf-8">';
     $html .= '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">';
     $html .= '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">';
     $html .= '<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>">';
     $html .= '<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>">';
     return $html;
     <?php
 }?>
```

here you only print your variable instead of return html. so meta is not properly display. so above code is working for you

Comment: Thanks. but doesn't really answer my question . My current code for generating tags work fine. I was wondering if one could edit the meta tags through a form or such without seeing the code?